# NSNotification called before view controller is initialised completely

Tags: ios, nsnotification

Hi I have a viewcontroller in a tabview controller. I decided to use NSNotification to flag when views in the tabview controller need to update their data. Previously each had logic to tred to decided the state of the data model and update accordingly.

My update code calls some stuff that in turn call delegate methods. These were all working when not using notification.

My first attempt at notifying seemed to call the selector before the view controller had initialised (before viewDidload at least). Among other thing the delegate methods were never called when the update in the notification selector was run and the view controller didn't get updated. Seems like the viewcontroller is in some unknown state.

I ran a test and put the same update code in the viewDidLoad and only called the notification code after the viewDidLoad had been called. This works.

My question is  ,is there another way of preventing the notification selector method being called before viewDidLoad or the object is otherwise correctly initialised.

I am using  storyboard so I am not programming the creation of views etc.

I hope this is clear - posting a whole bunch of code would not had been any easier.

Comment: When are you registering your view controller to receive the notifications?

Comment: Why not always call your update code when you initialize your view controller? Then register for the `NSNotification` specifically for the case when the view controller is *already* initialized and needs to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, both right! I set up the Notification in app delegate. I should put it at the end of viewDidLoad. Then it is only called when there is a subsequent update and I don't need a flag to stop the first notification from doing an update before the object is up and running.